# UML Association meaning

Tags: uml

I don't get what the association arrow means. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(object-oriented_programming). Does it mean that Class1 uses something of Class2?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arrow means Navigability and according to UML 2.5 specification.

> Navigability means that instances participating in links at runtime (instances of an Association) can be accessed efficiently from instances at the other ends of the Association

So in the following diagram instance of Class have access to instance of Class3.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of UML you’re using. In UML 2.5 it’s navigability, with a different notation (a ‘dot’) indicating end ownership (I.e. which class owns the relationship — e.g. with a reference attribute). In UML 1 it means a combination of navigability and end-ownership.

https://www.omg.org/ocup-2/documents/getting_it_right_on_the_dot.pdf

[image: UML2 and UML1 arrows and dots]

Comment: Oh. I was not aware that they published a separate paper on this topic.

Comment: Yes, a nice little 2.5 pager!

Comment: so basically has a relationship?

Comment: muszeo is pointing out the use of the dot notation which will tell that the opposite end has an owned attribute (containing an object reference) so it can talk to the dot-attached object. The use of directed association has more or less been replaced by the dot notation (it had been introduced with 2.1 IIRC). I don't think it's in much favor of UML users since it's harder to recognize, but that's another story. You should use dot notation instead of the arrows.